# Calculating the flux through $K=${$(x,y,z)|(z-1)^2=x^2+y^2, 0 \leq z \leq 1$} with $F=-y \hat{\imath}+x \hat{\jmath}+z \hat{k}$

Tags: calculus, vector-analysis, vector-fields

The surface $S \subset \Bbb R^3$ is a union of

$K=${$(x,y,z)|(z-1)^2=x^2+y^2, 0 \leq z \leq 1$}

and

$C=${$(x,y,z)|x^2+y^2 \leq 1 , z=0$}

Given is the vectorfield $F=-y \hat{\imath}+x  \hat{\jmath}+z \hat{k}$

Calculate the flux through $S$ with an outward pointing normal, without using the divergence theorem.

I calculated the flux through $C$, which is $0$. Because $F \bullet \hat{N}=( -y \hat{\imath}+x  \hat{\jmath}+z \hat{k}) \bullet -\hat{k}= -z \hat {k}$, but $z=0$ in $C$ so, $F \bullet \hat{N}=0$.

I'm having trouble with calculating the flux through $K$. This is because I find it difficult to find a normal vector. Tips and hints about this are appreciated !

Comment: You can rewrite $K$ as $x^2 + y^2 - (z-1)^2 = 0$. Take the gradient to find a normal. It would be $2x \hat{i} + 2y \hat{j} - 2(z-1) \hat{k}$.

Comment: And then just divide it by the length?

Comment: Yes for a unit normal. Make sure to check whether it's outward pointing. If you draw your region, it seems to be the correct orientation already. In the end when you calculate the surface integral, the complicated length/norm term cancels out automatically.